# Any Inner join doesn't work to combine two tables using date

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse

I use clickhouse. The following code doesn't work, although this type of writing the query works in other SQL databases.

```
    select * 
    from 
        ((select event_date, uniq(attraction_hash) 
          from table_1
          where event_date >= toDate('2021-07-13 00:00:00') - 30
            and event_date <= toDate('2021-10-13 00:00:00')
            and trans_type in ('initial', 'trial')
group by event_date)
    any inner join
        (select event_date, uniq(feid) 
         from table_2
         where event_date >= toDate('2021-07-13 00:00:00') - 30
           and event_date <= toDate('2021-10-13 00:00:00')
         group by event_date)
    using event_date)
```

The following error occurs:

> Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 302 ('any') (line 7, col 1): any inner join (select event_date, uniq(feid) from table_1 WHERE event_date >= toDate('2021-07-13 00:00:00') - 30 AND eve. Expected UNION ALL (version 20.9.2.20 (official build))

Please help

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: Yes, it's the syntax of clickhouse and "any inner join" is eligible here

Comment: Please use code block format with appropriate line breaks for error messages because otherwise some characters are markdown meta/format characters. Please avoid greetings, thanks, etc.

Comment: A subquery argument for a JOIN must be followed by an alias. But not for a UNION. USING takes parentheses. Show that you have code that works without ANY before with it. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow this way:

```sql
SELECT
    number,
    c,
    u
FROM
(
    SELECT
        number,
        count() AS c
    FROM numbers(100)
    WHERE number > 10
    GROUP BY number
) AS t1
ANY INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        number,
        uniq(number % 2) AS u
    FROM numbers(16)
    WHERE number > 10
    GROUP BY number
) AS t2 USING (number)

/*
┌─number─┬─c─┬─u─┐
│     14 │ 1 │ 1 │
│     15 │ 1 │ 1 │
│     12 │ 1 │ 1 │
│     11 │ 1 │ 1 │
│     13 │ 1 │ 1 │
└────────┴───┴───┘
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. Just 5 minutes ag  arrived at this solution – clickhouse, as opposed to other sql dwh, only allows to join two table when you extract variable from the first